# GAE Datastore read operation pricing

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Suppose if we do

```
select * from Products where category = "electronics"
```

versus

```
select name, price from Products where category = "electronics"
```

What impact will it have on datastore pricing ?

From Google Cloud Platform doc it is written:
Projection queries that do not use the distinct on clause. This type of query is counted as a single entity read for the query itself. The individual results are counted as small operations.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to trade off with respect to pricing.  The projection query will need a composite index which will cause an increase in storage costs, but the queries will be cheaper by O(num results * read price).